# xcode 7 - Unable to run app on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I am building an app with Xcode 7 and while I successfully installed the app on my iPhone and iPad Pro - I am unable to do so on my secondary iPhone.

I tried connecting my brother's iPhone and it still gives me the same error.

The error I receive is:

[image: Error Image]

I tried removing my account, deleting and re-adding all provisioning profiles, restarting my Mac and none of it works.

Point to note: I **do not** have a paid membership account but in my understanding, that shouldn't be the reason for it. Also, the app is successfully running on two of my devices and failing to run in any other devices.

Comment: can you share you provisioning profile settings ?

Comment: in Build Settings there is a section named `Code signing`

Comment: Its set to `iOS Developer` and Provisioning Profile is set to `Automatic`